# Confusion concerning transition wavenumbers

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics

I have been trying to calculate the wavenumber for the 2p -> 5d transition in hydrogren. Using the formula: $ R_H (\frac{1}{n^2_f}-\frac{1}{n^2_i}) $ would give me a negative answer. I have never seen a negative answer to this type of question before, but though it feels intuitively wrong I can't think of why this would be an issue?

Comment: Your formula $ R_H (\frac{1}{n^2_f}-\frac{1}{n^2_i}) $ works when a electron **emits** a photon. While in your question the electron is "absorbing" a photon to go to a higher energy state.

Comment: Thanks @HrishabhNayal, so can I reverse $n_f $ and $n_i$ or should I use a different formula entirely?